# MYSQL Update из другой таблицы, зависает

Tags: mysql

Знатоки!
Прошу помочь, мне нужно обновить одну таблицу данными из другой, но запрос зависает! `table 2` большая, может, поэтому?
Или я неправильный использую код? Использую `MIN`, т.к. в`table 2` несколько записей с одинаковыми `art`, но разными `price`

```
update `table1` t1 set `price` = (select min(`price`)
from `table2` t2
where t2.`art`=t1.`art`)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN ( SELECT art, MIN(price) price
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY art ) t2 ON t2.art=t1.art
set t1.price = t2.price;
```

Comment: Ваш код работает в разы быстрее (раз в 200), спасибо!

Comment: @Антон *в разы быстрее (раз в 200)* Значит, в table1 порядка 200 записей...